# Use a db table to control from 5 to several hundred subroutine callsfrom one location

Tags: java, dynamically-generated

There is one thought of including code like this in a Java application.

```
Evaluate External Type Code
When 1 
  Call L.Services Parm1, Parm2, Parm3,Parm4, Parm5, Parm6
When 2 
  Call T.Services Parm1, Parm2, Parm3
When 3 
  Call C.Services Parm1, Parm2, Parm3,Parm4, Parm5, Parm6
When 4
  Call D.Services Parm1, Parm2
When 4
  Call X.Services Parm1, Parm2, Parm3,Parm4, Parm5
When other
  Call Invalid
End Evaluate
```

There will be likely additions of calls added over the development cycle.  I haven't developed anything in Java, my experience is mainframe assembler, COBOL, PL/1, and database applications.
The Parm fields can be to/from and there will be a different number of parms for each subroutine.

I know this can be done in assembler, C and PL/1 however Java?

My preference would be to have a small table with the name of the called routine and a list of all the parameters.
This would allow the query of the CALL Table with the CALL ID to return the routine name and all parmaters. (as an array?)
With this method, there would not be any code changes in the controlling module to add new functionallity, only an insert into the CALL Table.

Can this be done in Java?